# Live Streaming Tweets without being rate limited

Tags: twitter, request, jsonp

I'm creating a dashboard that will plot geo-enabled tweets on a map as they are made. The huge problem is that in order for me to simulate it being truly live, a new request is made ever second.

[image]

Per Twitter's API limitations, REST API calls are limited to 150/350 per hour for unAuth/OAth (respectively), so making a call every second is not going to work. Perhaps I'll have to settle for a refresh delay, but I'm curious as to whether or not there is a workaround.

Is there a way for me to have a truly live feed that puts a dot on the map as soon as a user tweets it?

Here's a portion of my code for loose reference:

```
// url is set above with the search query
function firstQuery(terms, oldestTweet, page, pic) {
    getLimiter++;
    var encodedTerms = encodeURIComponent(terms);
    $.getJSON(url + '&page=' + page + '&max_id=' + oldestTweet + '&include_entities=1&result_type=recent&rpp=100&callback=?', function(tweets) {
        if ($(tweets.results).length) {
            if (storedLatestTweet < tweets.results[0].id) {
                storedLatestTweet = tweets.results[0].id;
            }
            page++;
            tweetCount = tweetCount + tweets.results.length;
            storedOldestTweet = tweets.results[tweets.results.length - 1].id;
            harvest(tweets, pic);
            firstQuery(terms, oldestTweet, page, pic);
        } else {
            // continue to loop if more need to be plotted with the oldest tweet id known
            if (getLimiter < 65 && tweetNumber < 10) {
                page = 1;
                firstQuery(terms, storedOldestTweet, page, pic);
            }
            return latestLoop(); // loops the request
        }
    });
}

function latestLoop() {
    latest(terms, storedLatestTweet, page, pic);

    // use queryLoop so that the timeout can be killed on new search
    queryLoop = setTimeout(function() {
        latestLoop();
    }, 1000); // the loop rate of the request...1 second isn't gonna work
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do live processing on twitter through Twitter Stream API. But stream api doesn't send you all tweets, you have to specify either keywords to filter tweets containing given keywords or userIds to follow tweets coming from given users or geo location to filter tweets coming from a particular place. Also there are limits on number of keywords, user ids to follow etc. And lastly twitter will give you upmost 1% percent of the tweets in the global traffic. So for example if you come up with a filter which tracks less than 1% of the global trafic you will get all the tweets (in theory) otherwise you will miss some tweet as twitter won't share them with you.

There is also public sample stream which gives you some sample data from twitter. If you are just doing this for an experiment it can help you. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/sample

My suggestion to you would be to determine what exactly you want to follow on twitter and come up with a clever filter for streaming api and track the results from your map. You can also boost your result by again calling search api periodically to fill the missing data in your application (sometimes tweets are not delivered due to several reason in live streaming, and through search api you can retrieve them)

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/public

Comment: It would be for specific keywords, but these would most likely be far <1% of the entire firehose. In order to implement this, would I just get rid of the request loop entirely since the connection is left open to the Twitter Stream?

Comment: Exactly. Just open one connection an watch the data stream. You might need to restart the connection when you need to change the filter (adding keyword etc.) or an exception is thrown due to some reason (twitter api works smoothly in most of the time, the connection doesn't get interrupted that much, but it might happen too. Because of this rare chance, it is a good idea to monitor the status of the stream.

Comment: I'm having a little bit of trouble figuring out how to translate my loop into something that can process the stream. Could you possibly help me out?

Comment: Well in the code you given you are using search api which is different than stream api. Unfortunately I don't know the language you have written that code and can't modify it correctly for you. I use java and twitter4j for streaming twitter. In the following document just check the latest example (9th one) http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html

Comment: Btw your streamer needs to work as another process and it will work always to ensure that you don't miss any data. Check the streaming api to see the required parameters for twitter. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/filter